# How filter argument in Power BI DAX CALCULATE interact with outer filter context on different column in same table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables:

Date: sample data:

Date:

| Date | Month Year |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Jan 2023 |
| 2023-01-02 | Jan 2023 |
| ... | ... |

Sales:

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 9 |
| 2023-02-01 | 3 |
| 2023-03-01 | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 | 4 |
| 2023-05-01 | 2 |

I have a measure:

```
Sales _ = CALCULATE( SUM(Sales[Sales]) , 'Date'[Date] = DATE(2023,5,1) )
```

I created a table based on 'Date'[Month Year] and measure [Sales_] which shows [Sales_] has same value for all [Month Year] which is sales for DATE(2023,5,1):

| Month Year | Sales _ |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2023 | 2 |
| Feb 2023 | 2 |
| Mar 2023 | 2 |
| Apr 2023 | 2 |
| May 2023 | 2 |

The result I'm expecting is that there's value for only May 2023 and other rows should be blank since inner and outer filter context match only for May 2023. Outer filter is on 'Date'[Month Year] and inner filter is on 'Date'[Date], so my understanding is that in this case inner filter does not override outer filter since they are on different columns in same table.

Why [Sales_] has same value for all [Month Year] in the table?

Please find pbix here: [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1COJQpiGCDoS-pYRPP7AZU3-ZJIDrAp1f/view?usp=sharing) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi, filter propogate from dimension to fact your internal filter by default filtered for dim[date] after the sales[date] is filtered for may so to preserve this date[date] filter so it will take date[date] for may docs recommend you to use keepfilters

```
Sales _ = 
VAR SUM_D = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Sales]),
    
    KEEPFILTERS('Date'[Date] = DATE(2023,5,1))
)
RETURN IF(ISBLANK(SUM_D), "", SUM_D)
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, but my questions is why Sales is same for all Month Year when using the following measure: Sales _ = CALCULATE( SUM(Sales[Sales]) , 'Date'[Date] = DATE(2023,5,1) ) , considering calculate filter argument is on 'Date'[Date], filter context in table visual is on 'Date'[Month Year], these two filters are on different columns in 'Date' table.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for *why* the measure gives the same value for each month is because that's what you have written code for.

The code:

```
Sales _ = CALCULATE( SUM(Sales[Sales]) , 'Date'[Date] = DATE(2023,5,1) )
```

Specifically says "give me the sum of all rows in `Sales[Sales]`, but take whatever is the current evaluation context from `'Date'` and replace it with this specific filter on date".

So for any row in your table visual, it will give you the aggregated sum of `Sales[Sales]` for `2023-05-01`.

Edit: When you talk about "outer" and "inner" filters, I don't think you are using proper terminology. When you use e.g. `YearMonth` as a visual categorical dimension, you are only creating an evaluation context that is used by the engine to access the corresponding rows in `'Date'[Date]` that are described by this dimension. In your code, you are actively changing your filter context to specifically look away from any filters to `'Date'[Date]` and replace it with your single date instead.

Please note: This is exactly what makes `CALCULATE` both powerful, useful, and necessary to master in Power BI.